# Spring Cloud Data Flow Server Memory Management

Tags: spring-cloud-dataflow

- I am using docker-compose to stand dataflow server on an openstack
  machine with 32 gb ram I have one deployed stream, and 4 undeployed
  streams. I have not set deployer properties inside docker-compose.yml

When running

```
docker stats datalow-server

I see : memory usage as  26 GB/32 GB
```

I suppose that I need to use JVM restriction by using the property

```
spring.cloud.deployer.local.javaOpts
```

1. Question: What is the recommended -Xmx and -Xms values to be used
   for dataflow server container

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are using the `local` SCDF server implementation.

> What is the recommended -Xmx and -Xms values to be used for Data Flow server

There are no recommended values as it heavily depends on what/how many apps you try to deploy in the same instance. For SCDF local, it launches all the stream app instances in the same VM/container/machine so it is shared by the running apps.

Comment: Thank you, Yes I am using the local SCDF implementation. I have one stream deployed with 5 apps running. Rabbit -> Filter ->Custom Processor ->HttpClient->Log. Things look better when I changed the docker-compose.yml file to include:   spring.cloud.deployer.local.javaOpts=-Xmx8192m, now the docker-stats on dataflow-server is hovering at:  9.472GiB / 31.26GiB Memory usage.

Comment: Although what seems to work best is individual restrictions to java apps running inside the stream/pipeline e.g. spring.cloud.deployer.memory 300 mb